# Github - Subindo Arquivos

Tags: github

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/patricchubaca/Calculadora-em-JavaScrip.git'

Estou aprendendo a subir arquivos e na hora do "git push -u origin master" ele da este error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/patricchubaca/Calculadora-em-JavaScrip.git' e ele da o erro. Ja pesquisei e nao achei nada referente alguem para ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você deu git clone? Caso não, faça: `git clone https://github.com/patricchubaca/Calculadora-em-JavaScrip.git seu-diretorio/`. A pasta deve ser vazia, e somente depois você coloca o código nela.

Após isso você poderá dar o git push.

Comment: Entao, eu so quero subir meu arquivo para o github  e da este erro

Comment: Você não respondeu o que eu perguntei. Para subir, primeiro precisa dar o git glone para 'parear' com sua pasta, e depois der o push, ele enviará corretamente para seu repositório. Da forma como você está fazendo, como ele sabe para onde está sendo feito o push? Talvez existe outra forma, mas eu desconheço. Ou talvez a forma que eu faço já faz por debaixo dos panos a outra forma, talvez manual de se fazer isso. Mas sempre faço dessa forma que falei e é muito simples! Enfim, sinta-se a vontade para testar e voltar aqui depois para falar se deu certo ou não dessa forma que eu falei.

Comment: Desculpe, so hoje que. Entao, segui os comandos da pagina do Github mesmo e deu certo  dei o push depois ele pedia um comando e executei e deu certo

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.